# Binding Repeater with Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int,[object]>

Tags: asp.net, dictionary, repeater, eval, bind

I am new to .NET, so I'm struggling with this. I have a content page, with a repeater control. I have a Dictionary, which is a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int,[object]>>`. I want the value of the controls inside the repeater control to get it from the object attributes - Candidate Name, would be `object.CandName`, candidate phone would be `object.Phone` etc.

I am not sure how to use `Eval` for this type of Dictionary. Most of the examples point to `Eval("Value")`, but it is not giving the correct value for me. Kindly help!

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="content" Runat="Server">
  <div id="rcontent"> 
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <asp:Label ID="lblerror" runat="server" Text="" Visible="true" CssClass="alert"></asp:Label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div id ="rptdiv">
      <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <div id="Div3"> 
            <table class="GridViewStyleNoBorder" width=750px cellspacing="0" border="0" >
              <tr>
                <td class="PagerStyle" colspan="4"> 
                  <asp:Label ID="lblName" Runat="server"
Text='<%= Need the value of the [object].objectproperty from dictionary here %>' />
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
```

This is my `Page_Load` code behind - `BLDecision` is my business layer code, which returns the dictionary and dictionary values are correct. I checked them in debug mode.

Code Behind:

```
Dictionary(int, Dictionary(int, InterviewFeedback)) ;

CandIntDetails = new Dictionary(int, Dictionary(int, InterviewFeedback))();

BLDecision objBLDecision = new BLDecision();
int ReqCategoryID = 0;
if (Request.QueryString["ReqCategoryID"] != null)
    ReqCategoryID = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["ReqCategoryID"].ToString());
CandIntDetails = objBLDecision.GetCandidatesforReqCategory(ReqCategoryID);

Repeater1.DataSource = CandIntDetails;
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

Should I use from codebehind, can I not do `Eval('<% ....%>')` in the aspx page?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You should describe the format of your data more precisely.  At one point you say it's a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, InterviewFeedback>>`, and at another, you imply that you're working with a `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, InterviewFeedback>>`.  What exactly does the dictionary contain, and what do you want your output to look like?  Do you want things grouped by dictionary key, or were you wanting to access all values for a particular key?

Comment: It is : Dictionary(int, Dictionary(int, InterviewFeedback)) ;
I want to access and display all values of a particular key - each row all values need to be accessed and displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it with only one repeater. Since you have a container inside a container, you need a Repeater inside a repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
<ItemTemplate>
<div id="Div3"> 
    <table class="GridViewStyleNoBorder" width=750px cellspacing="0" border="0" >
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("Value")' >
      <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
    <td class="PagerStyle" colspan="4"> 
         <asp:Label ID="lblName" Runat="server"
        Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
    </td>
    </tr>

      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>


    </table>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I added another Repeater, but could not access the value directly, since the Value of the Dictionary is a Business Object. So I did this on the code behind. I am able to get the records value displayed. But it displays only one record. It has totally 3 records, but displays the first row, but doesnt display the rest. Should I loop it somewhere, am I missing something.

Answer (score 0):

If `CandIntDetails` is a `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, InterviewFeedback>>`, you need to extract from that the specific collection you want to use as the data source of your repeater.  The reason why is because you want to render a collection of `InterviewFeedback` objects, which `CandIntDetails` is *not*.  `CandIntDetails` probably looks something like this:

```
{
    46: {
        0: [InterviewFeedback],
        1: [InterviewFeedback],
        2: [InterviewFeedback]
    }
}
```

It's not clear from your post what the keys are for the inner or outer dictionaries, so this is speculative.  If the outer key is the the category ID (not sure why `GetCandidatesforReqCategory` would return something like that), and if you don't care about the inner dictionary keys, you can extract your data source like this:

```
Repeater1.DataSource = CandIntDetails[ReqCategoryID].Values;
```

That will make your data source a straight collection of `InterviewFeedback` objects.  Once that's your data source, you can `Eval` to access the properties of the `InterviewFeedback` objects.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Works now.